# How to search multiple strings from Firebase Data base if the data is not user account and in Java not kotlin?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

How to search multiple String from firebase Database if the data is not user account and fetch on simple Recyclerview and in Java not Kotlin. Please dont mark it as duplicate because this is my last hope.... Seriously this answer is not available in stackoverflow in this manner....

I have already tried stackover flow answers and also other quora but failed because those solution present in these sites are based on user interface or in kotlin language

I want to search data from .orderByChild("title") and .orderByChild("description")
but it is only searching single string.

> MainActivity

```
     mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        //set layout as LinearLayout
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        //send Query to FirebaseDatabase
        mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("Data");
    }

    //search data
    private void firebaseSearch(String searchText) {

        //convert string entered in SearchView to lowercase
        final String query = searchText.toLowerCase();


        final Query firebaseSearchQuery = mRef.orderByChild("title").startAt(query).endAt(query + "\uf8ff");
firebaseSearchQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.child(query).hasChild("title")){
                mRef.child(query).child("title").removeValue();

            }else {


    }}
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Model, ViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter =
                new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Model, ViewHolder>(
                        Model.class,
                        R.layout.row,
                        ViewHolder.class,
                        firebaseSearchQuery
                )
                {
                    @Override
                    protected void populateViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, Model model, int position) {
                        viewHolder.setDetails(getApplicationContext(), model.getTitle(), model.getDescription(), model.getImage(), model.getUrl());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

                        ViewHolder viewHolder = super.onCreateViewHolder(parent, viewType);

                        viewHolder.setOnClickListener(new ViewHolder.ClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onItemLongClick(View view, int position) {
                                //TODO do your own implementaion on long item click
                            }
                        });

                        return viewHolder;
                    }


                };

        //set adapter to recyclerview
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }


    //load data into recycler view onStart
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Model, ViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter =
                new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Model, ViewHolder>(
                        Model.class,
                        R.layout.row,
                        ViewHolder.class,
                        mRef
                ) {
                    @Override
                    protected void populateViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, final Model model, int position) {

                        viewHolder.setDetails(getApplicationContext(), model.getTitle(), model.getDescription(), model.getImage(),model.getUrl());
                    viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            final String url = model.getUrl();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewsWebView.class);
                            intent.putExtra("id", url);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });


                    }


                    @Override
                    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

                        final ViewHolder viewHolder = super.onCreateViewHolder(parent, viewType);

                        viewHolder.setOnClickListener(new ViewHolder.ClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                                //Views
                                TextView mTitleTv = view.findViewById(R.id.rTitleTv);
                                TextView mDescTv = view.findViewById(R.id.rDescriptionTv);
                                ImageView mImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.rImageView);
                                //get data from views
                                String mTitle = mTitleTv.getText().toString();
                                String mDesc = mDescTv.getText().toString();
                                Drawable mDrawable = mImageView.getDrawable();
                                Bitmap mBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) mDrawable).getBitmap();

//                            
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onItemLongClick(View view, int position) {
                                //TODO do your own implementaion on long item click
                                TextView mTitleTv = view.findViewById(R.id.rTitleTv);
                                TextView mDescTv = view.findViewById(R.id.rDescriptionTv);
                                ImageView mImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.rImageView);
                                //get data from views
                                String mTitle = mTitleTv.getText().toString();
                                String mDesc = mDescTv.getText().toString();
                                Drawable mDrawable = mImageView.getDrawable();
                                Bitmap mBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) mDrawable).getBitmap();


                                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), PostDetailActivity.class);
                                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                                mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                                byte[] bytes = stream.toByteArray();
                                intent.putExtra("image", bytes); //put bitmap image as array of bytes
                                intent.putExtra("title", mTitle); // put title
                                intent.putExtra("description", mDesc); //put description
                                startActivity(intent); //start activity

                            }
                        });

                        return viewHolder;
                    }

                };

        //set adapter to recyclerview
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        //inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it present
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                firebaseSearch(query);
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                //Filter as you type
                firebaseSearch(newText);
                return false;
            }
        });
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //handle other action bar item clicks here
        if (id == R.id.action_sort) {
            //display alert dialog to choose sorting
            showSortDialog();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void showSortDialog() {
        //options to display in dialog
        String[] sortOptions = {" Newest", " Oldest"};
        //create alert dialog
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Sort by") //set title
                //.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_sort) //set icon
                .setItems(sortOptions, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // The 'which' argument contains the index position of the selected item
                        // 0 means "Newest" and 1 means "oldest"
                        if (which == 0) {
                            //sort by newest
                            //Edit our shared preferences
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSharedPref.edit();
                            editor.putString("Sort", "newest"); //where 'Sort' is key & 'newest' is value
                            editor.apply(); // apply/save the value in our shared preferences
                            recreate(); //restart activity to take effect
                        } else if (which == 1) {
                            {
                                //sort by oldest
                                //Edit our shared preferences
                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSharedPref.edit();
                                editor.putString("Sort", "oldest"); //where 'Sort' is key & 'oldest' is value
                                editor.apply(); // apply/save the value in our shared preferences
                                recreate(); //restart activity to take effect
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
        builder.show();
    }

}

enter code here
```

Comment: I don't understand. You say that you are trying to search the database but in the `onDataChange` you are removing some values. Can you please provide more infos?

Comment: I have tried this code. this is not the right code I have copied it from some where. Here some conditions willl applied for child but I don't know what code should write here..... to searchtext from  "title"+"description"

Comment: I want to search multiple strings texts values like "title" and "description".

Comment: I am still waiting ....... Please answer my question